# How can I check checkboxes based on values?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am returning a JSON data structure that I split and populate my array like so:

```
var arrayValues = data.contents.split('|');

// arrayValues = 1,3,4
```

How can I check the corresponding checkboxes based on the array values?

My HTML looks like this:

```
 <div id="divID">
     <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" /> Test 1<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" /> Test 2<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" /> Test 3<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="4" /> Test 4<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="5" /> Test 5<br />                           
 </div>
```

Comment: What criteria would cause you to check / uncheck the boxes

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this using attribute selector

```
$.each(arrayValues, function(i, val){

   $("input[value='" + val + "']").prop('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: This worked great...all I had to do was include the parent div tag. Thanks!

Comment: That should be `.prop('checked',true)` -- although JS considers the string "checked" to be true, so the end result is the same.

Comment: This is simpler : `$('input[name="test"]').val(arrayValues);`

See details in my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44592561/2017567]

Answer (score 16):

Javascript

```
$.each(arrayValues, function (index, value) {
  $('input[name="test"][value="' + value.toString() + '"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: This looks to be more accurate than ShankarSangoli's solution, although I don't see why the `.toString()` in the middle is necessary. Surely `value` will be a string in all circumstances.

Comment: @mblase75 ... just a habit of mine.

Comment: Yes, the author might have put toString to take care of cases where the value is a an integer, but ya, that too would be of string type in DOM

Answer (score 3):

Simpler :

```
$('input[name="test"]').val(arrayValues);
```

This will check the values from the array and deselect the others.

From the JQuery's doc : http://api.jquery.com/val/

> val() allows you to pass an array of element values. This is useful
>   when working on a jQuery object containing elements like <input
>   type="checkbox">, <input type="radio">, and <option>s inside of a
>   <select>. In this case, the inputs and the options having a value that
>   matches one of the elements of the array will be checked or selected
>   while those having a value that doesn't match one of the elements of
>   the array will be unchecked or unselected, depending on the type.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your array and do an attribute search on jQuery

```
var i = 0;
while (arrayValues.length < i) {
  var val = arrayValues[i];
  $('#divID input[value="' + val + '"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
  i++;
}
```

docs : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Okay took me a moment to sort out my error in the code.
I guess this question is answered by *ShankarSangoli* now.

I hope you don't mind me posting my solution either way. I'm just curious if this is worse for performance etc.

```
var arrayValues = new Array(1,3,4);

$('#divID input').filter(function(){
    return ($.inArray( parseInt($(this).attr('value')), arrayValues)) != -1;
}).attr('checked', 'checked');
```